# How run Javascript function from php during Jquery request?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, smarty

I need a way to call a Javascript function during Jquery request from php.

All resquest of my site is made from Jquery by functions:Post(), get() and getJson(), but when try call a javascript from php nothing happen. :(

If I use submit of the html the javascript run well.

Then I would like to know what I need to do for the javascript work in this case?

**Example I**

My php code in index.php:

```
echo "<script>Message();</script>";
```

My JavaScript:

```
function Message()
{
    alert('JavaScript Executing!');
}
```

My Jquery code:

```
function Save()
{
    $.post
    (
        'index.php',
        {
            Action: 'Save'
        }
    )
}
```

Html Button:

```
<form>
<br><input type="button" value="Massage with Jquery!" onclick="Save()"><br>
<br><input type="submit" value="Message without Jquery!"><br>
</form>
```

I want click in the button "Message with Jquery" then to my php call the function javascript "Message".

Justifying the need:
I could call this JavaScript directly in jQuery callback. The problem is that who knows when to run this JavaScript, Message(), is the client. :?
And that jQuery, POST,  has several clients. :?
My views are reusable and only index.php know which javascript function should be executed or not.

**Example II**

Other example where the problem apper:

New.tpl

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
function Save()
{
    $.post
    (
        'index.php',
        {
            Action: 'Save'
        }
    )
}
function Message()
{
    alert('JavaScript Executing!');
}
</script>
<form>
<br><input type="button" value="Massage with Jquery!" onclick="Save()"><br>
<br><input type="submit" value="Message without Jquery!"><br>
</form>
```

index.php

```
<?php
if( !isset($_POST['Action']))
{
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."MeuTreinamentoPHP/smarty/templates/Controler/MySmarty.php");
        $MySmarty=MySmarty::getInstance();
        $MySmarty->Open('new.tpl');
}
echo "<script>Message();</script>";//It is essential that the JavaScript is called in index in this case. :?
?>
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: My php code<br><?php
echo "<script>Message();</script>";
?>

Comment: and your Message() function definition? plus add script type attributes.

Comment: so you want your php to return javascript which will be then executed? i still don't get what do you want. maybe you're looking for $.post("index.php", {Action: 'Save'}, function() { Message(); })

Comment: Durilka, the problem is that not all the times this function "Post" run the function "Message()" is run too . The only element that has this knowledge is the client, in thins case is the php. : (

Answer (score 2):

You have a misunderstanding here.

JQuery is a Javascript library. Both run on the client (browser).

PHP runs on the web server. Hence does not run Javascript.

You can get Javascript to request JSON etc from the web server - that may deliver the data using PHP

Comment: I agree with this, though the question is so unclear that it's hard to say if he's actually trying to have PHP call js functions, or whether the problem is that his jquery ajax calls are not evaluating php-generated javascript that is output as a string.

Comment: Ben D, when I use: echo "<script>Message();</script>"; The Jquery transorm "<script>Message();</script>" in string. But I want execut the JavaScript. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the JS

```
<?php
echo '<script>alert("JS in PHP.");</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean? This code is not tested

**mainphp.php** (or whatever the file name is)

```
<script>
    function save(){

    //Lets you know you will be executing
    alert('JavaScript Executing!');

    //Get Value
    var postVal = $("#ButtonValue").val();

    //Post the inputs data to the index file, to save maybe?
    //Then post back what you saved?
    $.post("index.php", { "postVal": postVal },
       function(data) {
         alert(data);
       });

    }
</script>

    //You Have this form, I added an ID

<?php
echo '
    <form>
    <br><input id="ButtonValue" type="button" value="Massage with Jquery!" onclick="Save()"><br>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Message without Jquery!"><br>
    </form>';
?>
```

**Index.php will have**

```
<?php

$postVal = $_POST['postVal'];
echo $postVal;

?>
```

This will alert the message **"Massage with Jquery!"** after you post it

Comment: First of all thanks for responding.
But unfortunately that is not my difficulty.
In this example, the index.php would have to directly call a javascript that was in mainphp.php.

Anyway thanks!

Comment: Why does this file have to even trigger it?  What are you trying to accomplish,, I think you need to explain your question more.

Comment: Because my views are reusable and only index.php know which javascript function should be executed or not.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to tell the javascript what to do after it does the ajaxy magic.

```
$.post("index.php", 
    {Action: 'Save'}, 
    function(data) { eval(data); }
)
```

this will effectively execute whatever javascript you return from server
in your php don't send script tag but simply the code you want to execute:

```
echo "Message();"
```

Simpler and better solution will be to return command codes from server and act depending on them in client. this way you'll have all your javascript where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Interesting your solution!
I was thinking that there was a solution like:
<?php
$ clientID = jQuery-> Give_me_client_id;

Execut_JavaScript_In_Cliente ($ clientID, "Message ()").
?>
There are?

Comment: So @Ed Heal is right. No. PHP is processed on server, the result is sent to the browser and processed by javascript there. Two different computers.

Comment: I understand.
Just left a single doubt.
Why when I click on:
<pre><code><br> <input type="submit" value="Message without Jquery!"> <br><pre><code>
The server can execute JavaScript on the client?

Comment: grumpy man(php server) drives you to some wasteland (browser) you take a shovel (jquery) and start digging (javascript), then you ask that man ($.post) for an pickaxe (data/javascript), you receive it and keep working (use it/eval it). server never dug a tiniest particle of dust. just gave you the tools.

Comment: Durilka, a malicious user could inject a malicious javascript on the site, there would be a way to avoid this security hole?

Comment: the problem is not the security issues (if your server is compromised - it doesn't matter anymore), the problem is separation of concerns, driver drives, digger digs.